# how to solve an equality containing tanh

Tags: python, sympy

I use the following example to try to solve the inequality containing tanh, but it produces the error

> TypeError: Equation should be a polynomial with Rational coefficients

Anyone knows how to solve it ?

```
from sympy import Symbol, S
from sympy.solvers.solveset import solveset
x=Symbol('x')
v=0.05*x-8.5
solveset((1-(2*exp(-v))/(exp(v)+exp(-v)))>0, x, S.Reals)
```

Comment: You really should upgrade your sympy version (currently at 1.9).  Apart from that, it often helps to avoid floats, and write numbers as rationals (e.g. `v = (5 * x + 850) / S(100)`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `exp` from SymPy:

```
from sympy import Symbol, S
from sympy.functions import exp
from sympy.solvers.solveset import solveset
x = Symbol('x')
v = 0.05*x-8.5
solveset((1-(2*exp(-v))/(exp(v)+exp(-v)))>0, x, S.Reals)
```

which yields

```
Interval.open(170.000000000000, oo)
```

Comment: I still have the same error "TypeError: Equation should be a polynomial with Rational coefficients." Maybe you can tell me your sympy and python version ? Mine are 1.3 and 3.7.1.

Comment: I used Python 3.8.5 and SymPy 1.9 with the above code without issues.

Comment: All of these things should be imported from top-level like `from sympy import ...` rather than from the specific submodule. The code here works fine for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Having updated the sympy version to 1.9, the code finally works well for me.

Btw, in my case, in order to update the sympy, I should also update python to a newer version (currently 3.9.7) from my older version (3.7.1) since each python version seems to correspond to (a) certain sympy version(s).